# What's the difference in meaning between "vaticination" and "prognostication"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I'm reading a scholarly book which is discussing various ancient and medieval practices of seeing the future, and the author is using both terms. What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**prognosticate**: "to foretell from signs or symptoms"  *Merriam Webster* (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prognosticate).  **Prognosis** is closely related, as in "the doctor's prognosis was that her leg would return to 95% of full function after surgery, physical therapy and exercise."

Mario Pei, in *The Families of Words* (Harper & Bros, 1962) traces prognosis from the IE root *gen, to know, through Greek (gi)gnosko.  This route also gives rise to agnostic and diagnose (among other English words).

***Vaticinate***: "(*rare*) to foretell, prophesy..from Latin vāticinārī from vātēs prophet + canere to foretell" *Collins English Dictionary* (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vaticinate)

*Merriam Webster* defines **vaticinate** as "prophesy, predict" and gives as an example:

"if he could really vaticinate the course of the stock market, he'd be rich enough to own Manhattan."

For vaticination, *M-W* gives the example: "the myopic prewar vaticinations that the conflict would be brief and relatively painless"

"signs and symptoms" or related terms are an integral part of the definitions of prognosticate that I have found.  For example, Websters New Collegiate says of prognosis "a knowing beforehand".  This sense of having a somewhat factual basis is absent from the definitions of vaticinate that I have turned up.

Does this distinction jibe with what appears in the book you are reading?

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes, knowing that distinction is compatible with and gives meaning to what's written, for example that a particular type of fortune-telling divination involved both prognostication and vaticination.

Comment: @Dronz Thanks for the acceptance and for teaching me a new word.